# HarmonyOS Mobile Pentest

Tags: android, security, harmonyos

I could not find any checklist for HarmonyOS mobile pentest. I know harmonyOS developed based on android and all android application works on HarmonyOS if i use hms instead of gms. So Android static analysis checlist is same for available for HarmonyOS?